# Evaluate the limit of function $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(9x^2+1)^{1/2}}{x+2}.$

Tags: limits, radicals

Find the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(9x^2+1)^{1/2}}{x+2}.$$
I want to divide each of the terms by the highest power of $x$ but I failed to elimite the square root on it.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(9x^2+1)^{1/2}}{x+2}\cdot\frac{1/x}{1/x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(9+1/x^2)^{1/2}}{1+2/x}=3$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(9x^2+1)^{1/2}}{x+2}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}{x}}{\frac{x+2}{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{9x^2+1}{x^2}}}{1+\frac{2}{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{x^2}}}{1+\frac{2}{x}}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}{x+2}&=\frac{3x}{x+2}\sqrt{1+\frac1{9x^2}}\\\\
&=3\left(1-\frac{2}{x+2}\right)\sqrt{1+\frac1{9x^2}}
\end{align}$$

Since we have the limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{x+2}\right)=1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{1+\frac1{9x^2}}=1$$

then the limit of interest is

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}{x+2}=3$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Set $\dfrac1x=h\implies h\to0^+, h>0$

$\sqrt{9x^2+1}=\sqrt{\dfrac{9+h^2}{h^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{9+h^2}}{|h|}=\dfrac{\sqrt{9+h^2}}h$ as $h>0$